# Create new syntax in vim matching # but not #{

Tags: regex, vim, syntax

I want to create a new syntax for vim to highlight the comments. This syntax uses # for comments, but curly brackets after # (e.g. #{foo=5}) is used for programming, which are not to be highlighted the same way as comments. I know that the syntax for # comment is

```
syntax match newComment '\v#.*$'
highlight link newComment Comment
```

So what should be in the regex part if I want

```
#foo=5
```

to be highlighted as a comment but

```
#{foo=5}
```

is treated as a normal line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated the requirements, @Conner's answer works well.  It will not match if <kbd>#</kbd> is the last character on the line, which may or may not be what you want.

If you do want a trailing <kbd>#</kbd> to match, or if you later change your mind and decide that `# {bar}` (note the space) should also be normal, then I suggest using the negative, zero-width `\@!` pattern:

```
:syn match newComment '#{\@!.*'
```

Replace `{` with `\(\s*{\)` if you like, or with `\%(\s*{\)` if you want to spare vim the trouble of saving backreferences.  If you prefer to use `\v` then it looks like

```
:syn match newComment '\v#%(\s*\{)@!.*'
```

which is just as long (counting the `\v`) as not using `\v`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make sure the `#` is not immediately followed by a `{` in your pattern match. Instead of `\v#.*$` use `\v#[^{].*$`. See `:help pattern.txt|1053`.